# mysql query (group by? distinct?)

Tags: mysql

table rows

```
no | f_member_id | f_teacher_id | f_class_date
 1 | jenny       | teacher_a    | 2017-12-03
 3 | jenny       | teacher_a    | 2017-12-05
 2 | jenny       | teacher_a    | 2017-12-04
 4 | tom         | teacher_a    | 2017-11-27
 5 | tom         | teacher_a    | 2017-11-28
```

"teacher_a" needs to see the result like this.

```
---------------
jenny | teacher_a | 2017-12-05
tom   | teacher_a | 2017-11-28

------
```

*** The most recent class date of student name of the class of teacher_a's class.

I made query like this. dosen't work.

```
 SELECT distinct(f_member_id), f_class_date 
 FROM `classroom` where f_teacher_id='teacher' 
 group by f_member_id 
 order by f_class_date desc
```

Comment: distinct is in conflict with group by

Answer (score 0):

```
select f_member_id, f_teacher_id ,max(f_class_date) from table group by f_member_id,f_teacher_id;
```